# Проверка переменной arg[4] в начале класса

Tags: python

никак не получается проверить существование переменной в начале класса, подскажите как реализовать?
начало кода класса:

```
class MButton():
    def __init__(self, *arg):
        self.parent = arg[0]
        self.limage = arg[1]
        self.lcommand = arg[2]
        self.rcommand = arg[3]
```

пробовал что-то типа этого:,
(и еще несколько вариантов...)

```
try:
    arg[4]
except IndexError:
    arg[4] = None
```

### Вопрос 2:

а что если такими вариантами? допустимо? что лучше?

Вариант-1:

```
Вызов:
self.test = MTest(width=10, height=10, **{'bdsize':1, 'bgcolor':2, 'parent':3})

class MTest():
    def __init__(self, width, height, **args):
        self.width=width
        self.height=height
        self.bdsize=args['bdsize']
        self.bgcolor=args['bgcolor']
        self.bdcolor=args['bdcolor']
        self.parent=args['parent']
```

Вариант-2:

```
Вызов:
self.test = MTest(**{'width':10, 'height':10, 'bdsize':1, 'bgcolor':2, 'parent':3})

class MTest():
    def __init__(self, **args):
        self.width=args['width']
        self.height=args['height']

        self.bdsize=args.get('bdcolor')
        self.bgcolor=args.get('bdcolor')
        self.bdcolor=args.get('bdcolor')
        self.parent=args.get('bdcolor')
```

Вариант-3:

```
Вызов:
self.test = MTest(**{'width':10, 'height':10, 'bdsize':1, 'bgcolor':2, 'parent':3})

class MTest():
    def __init__(self, **args):
        self.width=args.get('width')
        self.height=args.get('height')
        self.bdsize=args.get('bdcolor')
        self.bgcolor=args.get('bdcolor')
        self.bdcolor=args.get('bdcolor')
        self.parent=args.get('bdcolor')
        
        if not self.width == None or self.height == None:
            raise Exception('ERROR: Проверьте правильность введенных данных обязательных параметров width и height !')
```

Вариант-4:

```
Вызов:
self.test = MTest(width=10, height=10, bdsize=1, parent=3)

class MTest():
    def __init__(self, **args):
        self.width=args['width']
        self.height=args['height']
        self.bdsize=args.get('bdsize')
        self.parent=args.get('parent')
        self.bgcolor=args.get('bgcolor')
        self.bdcolor=args.get('bdcolor')
```

Вариант-5:

```
Вызов:
self.test = MTest(width=10, height=10, bdsize=1, parent=3)

class MTest():
    def __init__(self, width, height, bdsize=None, bgcolor=None, bdcolor=None, parent=None):
        self.width=width
        self.height=height
        self.bdsize=bdsize
        self.bgcolor=bgcolor
        self.bdcolor=bdcolor
        self.parent=parent
```

Comment: Проверить длину `args` и добить до необходимой через `append`

Comment: Не проще именованные параметры сделать со значениями по-умолчанию? `def __init__(self, parent=None, limage=None, lcommand=None, rcommand=None):`

Comment: почитайте про `**kwargs`  и метод словаря `get`.

Comment: По поводу второй части: допустимо, но лучше писать `test = MTest(width=10, height=10, bdsize=1, bgcolor=2, parent=3)` и аналогично для второго варианта

Comment: добавил 3 и 4 варианты, на мой взгляд 4 самый удачный. Ошибка выскочит только если упущены обязательные параметры. При этом остальные объявлять не обязательно, они могут быть пропущены. Только ошибка стандартная выскочит, а не та что я впишу.

Comment: @biomotor, все варианты с `**args` неудачные. Считайте что явное перечисление набора параметров в "заголовке" метода - это как документация. Там можно указать и желаемые типы аргументов, и значения по-умолчанию, например. Это легко обрабатывается IDE и выскакивает в подсказках при наборе кода. Оставляя один параметр со звездочками вы лишаете себя этой возможности.

Comment: можно 2 примера для понимания, а то не оч понял.... ? (пишу в Notepad2... проверяю через IDLE)

Comment: @insolor, Вариант 5 - Вы так имели ввиду? Как указать желаемый тип аргумента?

Comment: @biomotor написал ответом. IDLE не советую вообще использовать никогда (тем более что и редактируете не в нем). Типы можно проверять отдельно с помощью [mypy](http://www.mypy-lang.org) - устанавливается с помощью команды `pip install mypy` в cmd.

Comment: я хотел читать ошибки средствами самого python, без сторонних библиотек, собственно как и написать программу... пока нашел только IDLE для отладки. pycharm хороша конечно, но весит много и грузит долговато. я быстрее 5-10 окон блокнота открою и отредактирую чем он запустится.

Comment: @biomotor IDLE - это тоже стороннее приложение. Я знаю Notepad2, я писал в нем лет 15 назад. Но это просто редактор текста с подсветкой. Обычного редактора достаточно, если проект не слишком большой. В любом случае, объединять все параметры метода в один - это не то как нужно писать код.

Comment: @insolor, так а как указать тип переменной в классе?

Comment: @biomotor через двоеточие. В моем ответе есть пример и ссылка где можно почитать.

Comment: @insolor, все увидел, спасибо. а подскажите, как правильно указывать переменные? если короткие (bch), то непонятно становится, если длинные (color_backgground_context_hover...), большое нагромождение кода. я для себя определил, что удобней по группам color_, select_, size_ и т.д....  пока делаю так. (size_wborder), может наоборот сделать (s_windows_border) ?

Comment: @biomotor лучше не совсем короткие, и не очень длинные. Можно использовать внутренний объект-контейнер, чтобы было типа `mtest.colors.background_context_hover`

Comment: @insolor, сейчас часть параметров сделал глобальными (global select_theme; select_theme = "light") и подгружаю их из другого файла так: (from config import *). насколько это верно и как удобней вообще? стоит ли разделять по файлам config и theme? или вообще все в main закинуть. программа небольшая, по сути тулбар.

Comment: @biomotor в идеале лучше вообще не использовать global. Как вариант можно использовать класс `Config` в отдельном файле, в нем хранить все параметры, пример: https://pastebin.com/Qmjj9Ltv

Comment: По поводу разбиения на отдельные файлы - как вам удобнее. Раньше я неохотно делил код на файлы. В последнее время я пишу на Java - там фактически для каждого класса отдельный файл, теперь уже постепенно переношу эту практику на Python.

Comment: @insolor, там только один минус получается, при вызове: (Название_файла.название класса.переменная_или_функция) или как-то иначе? может убрать название класса, тогда как указать наследование (class Mbutton(Tk.Button):) ?

Comment: @biomotor если вы делаете импорт как `from file import Class`, то имя файла не нужно указывать (если вы про это)

Comment: @insolor, нет, я именно про наследование классом Mbutton() от класса Tk.Button. то есть так :  class Mbutton(Tk.Button):    def __init__(self, root): А про отдельные файлы когда приложение на android разбираешь, там так и есть все отдельно находится. Хорошая практика, думаю тоже перейду.

Comment: @biomotor никак не убирать название класса, так и оставить.

Comment: @biomotor если у вас в файле MButton2.py лежит класс MButton2, то делайте импорт `from MButton2 import MButton2`

Comment: @insolor, ошибся с названием класса, у меня в файле MButton2 класс MButton2, сделал так: (from MButton2 import *) (self.btn2 = MButton2(self, width=50, height=50, bdsize=3, bgcolor='red', bdcolor='green'))

Comment: @insolor, обязательно ли в начале класса нужно переназначать переменные, или можно работать напрямую с ними? : class MTest():
    def __init__(self, width, height, bdsize=None, bgcolor=None, bdcolor=None, parent=None):
        self.width=width
        self.height=height
        self.bdsize=bdsize
        self.bgcolor=bgcolor
        self.bdcolor=bdcolor
        self.parent=parent

Comment: @biomotor в обычных классах обязательно. Начиная с Python 3.7 появились датаклассы, там более простой синтаксис для создания класса: [Введение в Data classes](https://habr.com/ru/post/415829/)

Comment: Учту, интересно...

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113629/discussion-on-question-by-biomotor---arg4---).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас ограниченный набор параметров, лучше не прятать их за `*args` или `**kwargs`.

Рабочий вариант для самого первого случая:

```
class MButton():
    def __init__(self, parent, limage, lcommand, rcommand=None):
        self.parent = parent
        self.limage = limage
        self.lcommand = lcommand
        self.rcommand = rcommand
```

Последний параметр необязательный.

Для "Вариант-1":

```
class MTest():
    def __init__(self, width, height, bdsize=None, bgcolor=None, parent=None):
        self.width=width
        self.height=height
        self.bdsize=bdsize
        self.bgcolor=bgcolor
        self.parent=parent


test = MTest(width=10, height=10, bdsize=1, bgcolor=2, parent=3)
```

Также в заголовке методов можно указывать типы параметров, например:

```
class MTest():
    def __init__(self, width: int, height: int, bdsize: int=None, parent=None):
        self.width=width
        self.height=height
        self.bdsize=bdsize
        self.parent=parent
```

Если вы попытаетесь передать в параметр значение другого типа, PyCharm подсветит этот код, либо при проверке через mypy будет показана ошибка. При запуске кода в интерпретаторе правда ошибок может не быть, т.к. Python - язык с динамической типизацией (ошибка возникнет, например, если вы ожидаете что значение целочисленное, и вы попытаетесь работать с ним как с числом, а передали до этого, например, строку).

Про аннотации типа можно почитать здесь: [Введение в аннотации типов Python](https://habr.com/ru/company/lamoda/blog/432656/)

В любом случае, явное перечисление параметров метода можно считать видом документации. То что IDE и редакторы кода это умеют обрабатывать и выводят подсказки во время написания кода (см. скриншоты ниже) намного упрощает программирование (даже IDLE в интерактивном режиме выводит подсказку с параметрами). Указывая один параметр `*args` или `**kwargs` вы лишаете себя этих возможностей.

VSCode:
[image: Скрин VSCode]

PyCharm:
[image: Скрин PyCharm]

Answer (score 0):

почитайте про **kwargs и метод словаря get:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.one = kwargs.get("one")
        self.two = kwargs.get("two")
        self.three = kwargs.get("three")
        self.four = kwargs.get("four")
            
    def show(self):
        print(id(self))
        print(self.one)
        print(self.two)
        print(self.three)
        print(self.four)
        
d1 = {"one":1, "two":3, "three":3, "four":4}
d2 = {"one":1, "three":3, "four":4}

c1 = MyClass(**d1)
c2 = MyClass(**d2)

c1.show()
# 153208200
# 1
# 3
# 3
# 4

c2.show()
# 153208456
# 1
# None
# 3
# 4
```

Если нужно выводит ошибку при отсутствии параметра, то можно дописать,например:

```
if not self.one: # или if sel.one == None
    raise Exception('My error!')
```

Comment: а что вообще удобней, **kwargs  или def __init__(self, parent=None, limage=None, lcommand=None, rcommand=None) ?

Comment: kwargs удобней, потому что вам не нужно явно задавать аргументы при вызове экземпляра класса. а по сути - это одно и то же.

Comment: при вызове сделал так:   self.test = MTest(**{"bdsize":"bdsize", "bgcolor":"bgcolor", "parent":"parent"})

Comment: что еще за self.test? может, просто test?

Comment: а как сделать, чтобы выводилось сообщение об ошибке, если отсутствуют какие-либо главные элементы, к примеру 2 или 4 цифры позиция и размеры?

Comment: я обновил ответ

Comment: @biomotor, все же лучше явно указывать имена параметров `__init__`, чем передавать список 
или словарь. Если указать имена, то IDE вам подскажет где какой параметр. Если же передавать списком или словарем, то вам нужно будет копипастить или смотреть в код класса, если забудете какие вообще есть параметры.

Comment: А что мешает несколько параметров указать явно, к примеру 2 или 4 цифры позиция и размеры, и остальное передавать в виде списка ? Например так: MTest(width=10, height=10, **{"bdsize":"1", "bgcolor":"2", "parent":"3"}) да и вообще а зачем? если какая неисправность все равно лезть в код...

Comment: @biomotor разница в том, что если класс в другом файле, то вам не нужно будет лезть в этот файл, чтобы посмотреть какие параметры у класса: сравните [с именованными параметрами](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9uZl.png), и [с одним параметром `**kwargs`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ueOq.png)

Comment: Добавил варианты... что можете сказать?